# Compare the closest id using .closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, console, operators, jquery-events

I am checking whether the closest id to `selected` class is `toshow` or not.
It can be seen from the code that the condition should be true but its showing false in the console.

1. Why is it showing false?
2. How can I show its true in console?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo part 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
        <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
          <div id="toshow"">ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
            <li>li (direct parent)
              <button class="selected">span</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>   
      </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log($(".selected").closest("[id]") == "toshow");
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`closest` is a DOM selector function. The result is a reference to an element. You want to check against the `id` of the returned element:

```
  console.log($(".selected").closest("[id]").attr('id') == "toshow");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo part 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
        <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
          <div id="toshow"">ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
            <li>li (direct parent)
              <button class="selected">span</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>   
      </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log($(".selected").closest("[id]").attr('id') == "toshow");
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: That looks like good code.   Why not make it a runnable snippet?

Comment: It is already. This is just a duplicate of the snippet posted by @nikhil_2001 in the original question so it can show that it logs true after the change.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare attr, its returning element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo part 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="width:500px;">div (great-grandparent)
        <ul>ul (second ancestor - second grandparent) 
          <div id="toshow"">ul (first ancestor - first grandparent)
            <li>li (direct parent)
              <button class="selected">span</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </ul>   
      </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  console.log($(".selected").closest("[id]").attr("id") == "toshow");
</script>
</html>
```